# Not uniformly continuous

Tags: uniform-continuity

I know that a function $f:A→\mathbb{R}$ is not uniformly continuous iff there exists $ϵ>0$ and there exist  sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $A$ such that 
  $\lim_{n→∞} |x_n-y_n|=0$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|≥ϵ$ for all $n∈\mathbb{N}$.

I want to know if there is any other method to disprove the uniform continuity of a function, either by boundlessness of the function (or its derivative), or by using the graph of the function.

Thank you.

Comment: You can also find a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $(f(x_n))_n$ is not Cauchy.

Comment: Yes but any method by graph or boundlessness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an open and bounded interval $(a,b)$:

> **Theorem.** If $f\colon(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then it can be extended by continuity into a continuous (and thus uniformly continuous) function $\tilde{f}\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$.

As contrapositive, we get that if $f$ is unbounded on $(a,b)$, then it cannot be uniformly continuous. (Otherwise, it could be extended into a continuous $\tilde{f}$ bounded on $[a,b]$.)

*This fails if you consider an unbounded interval, of course. $f\colon x\in[0,\infty)\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous, but not quite bounded.*

Comment: Sin (1/x) on (0,1) can be the counter example for this as it is boundede on [0,1] but not uniformly continuous

Comment: @AshokSinghBhandari How is it a counterexample? It is simply a case where it does not apply.

Comment: So can we say that theorem is not applicable on every function?

Comment: *If* it is not bounded, *then* it is not uniformly continuous. That's an implication, not an equivalence; if the $f$ *is* bounded, you cannot say anything with this...

Comment: But f(x)= x is not bounded on R but still uniformly continuous

Comment: Yes, but $\mathbb {R} $ is hardly a bounded interval of the form $(a,b) $, is it? I had even added a last paragraph in italics to show how important that assumption was.

Comment: Yes i got it thank you and what about unbounded intervals.

Comment: I don't know of any such method for unbounded intervals -- as examples show, then it is possible to be uniformly continuous but unbounded, uniformly continuous but with unbounded derivative (or uniformly continuous but not differentiable).

Comment: Can we say in informal way that if the graph of function is trying to be parallel to y-axis i.e. derivative is tending to infinity, the function is loosing it's uniform continuity?